# Границы теней объектов. Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, procedural-generation

[image: Граница теней]

У меня есть простой процедурный ландшафт. Границы геометрии соединяются правильно, но вот тень и освещение ведёт себя странно (что видно скриншоте).

Как можно такое убрать, не меняя PipeLine? Использую Universal Render PipeLine. Вот его настройки:

[image: Настройки URP]